# Remove current password checking in the admin form of FOSUserBundle

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I use FOSUserBundle to create the member area of my Symfony project.
In the back office I would like to modify a user without knowing his password.
How to do that?

Comment: What exactly do you want to modify? What looks your current `User` entity like?

Comment: For example I want to modify their firstname, lastname or email. My User entity extends the User entity of FOSUserBundle with firstname, lastname, address and others entities relations.

Comment: and why do you need to know the users password for changing his database record?

Comment: Because the FOSUserBundle's form asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `User` entity of the *FOSUserBundle* works like any other entity. You need just two things:

### A controller action

Create your `AdminController` or what-ever you want to call it.

```
class AdminController extends Controller 
{

    /**
    * This action is responsible for the editing of existing user
    *
    * @param Request $request The Symfony2 Request Object
    * @param User    $user    The user that should be edited
    *
    * @return array|\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse
    *
    * @Template()
    * @Route("/edit/{slug}", name="user_edit")
    * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
    * @ParamConverter("user", class="YourBundle:User")
    */
    public function editAction(Request $request, User $user)
    {
        $form = $this->createForm(
            new UserType(),
            $user
        );

        if ($request->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            $form->submit($this->getRequest());
            if ($form->isValid()) {

                $manager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
                $manager->persist($event); 
                $manager->flush();

                $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add(
                    'success',
                    'The user has been updated successfully!'
                );

                // generate redirect somewhere... & return
            }
        }

        return array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'user' => $user
        );
    }
```

### A form type for your user

The `type` should look like this:

```
class UserType extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add(
            'firstname',
            'text',
            array(
            'label' => 'Firstname',
            'required' => true,
            )
        );

        $builder->add(
            'lastname',
            'textarea',
            array(
            'label' => 'Lastname',
            'required' => true,
            )
        );

        // add more fields here if you want to....
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(
            array(
            'data_class' => 'YourName\YourBundle\Entity\User'
            )
        );
    }

}
```

This gives you full control over your *database records* without knowing their password. Also checkout the documentation:

- [Create custom field types](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html)
- [Rendering Forms basics](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#form-rendering-basics)
- [Basic information about Controllers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html)

Last but not least: **Don't** forget to include the `use` Statements and change all `@Route` definitions and other paths.

Comment: OK. I created a copy of `RegistrationFormType` without included the `plainPassword` property. Then MyUserType include this copy. It works. So it's really impossible to remove a property of a parent form ?

Comment: Not it's not. Look at the [remove()](http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Form/FormBuilder.html#method_remove) method of the `FormBuilder` class.

Answer (score 1):

To never ask for current password, In `\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType.php`, remove from the builder `->add('plainPassword',...`